# MomentJs not returning correct hours

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I am trying to get hours from momentjs. But its not giving me correct hours according to the date I have provided. Its either giving me my local timezone hours or utc hours. But not the one which I have specified.

example:

`moment('2015-09-04T21:50:32+08:00').hours();`
gives me `18` which is according to my system's timezone

`moment('2015-09-04T21:50:32+08:00').utc().hours()`
gives me utc hours i.e. `13`.

I just want to retrieve the hours I have given with the timezone.

I want to achieve this with moment. I don't want to parse the string and get the information

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out your have to call `parseZone()` before retrieving the values.

`moment('2015-09-04T21:50:32+08:00').parseZone().hours();`
gives `21`